# How to set the "duration" parameter for a flanger with LFO oscillator

Tags: audio

I am reading this book [Designing Audio Effect Plugins in C++: For AAX, AU, and VST3 with DSP Theory.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138591939) Here I implemented the Flanger effect. Quick summary: A flanger effect is basically a echo effect but the delay parameter is changed with an LFO oscillator to give the "flanging" sound.

Here is the graph:

[image]

My problem is this version of flanger only has the following properties:

[image]

In modern DJ equipments you see flanger with options such as "1beats,2beats,4beats...". What I noticed is The smaller lfoRate is the longer my flanger effect becomes. So If I set lfoRate around 10.26, my flanger becomes 1/8beats flanger. The book does not mention anything related to this. So I wonder what is the relationship between lforate and "Xbeats" of flanger. Lets say that my music is 128 bpm, is there is a special formula which is used to calculate lfoRate so that I have 4 beats flanger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LFO rate is the speed of the delay modulation. One full cycle is going from "down" to up" back to "down" again. It's in Hz, i.e. "per second". Let's says the music is 120 bpm and your LFO rate is 0.5Hz. 120 pbm is 2 beats per second or 4 beats per flanger cycle.

Beats Per Cycle = Music_speed/60/flanger_rate